# Getting uniform date format from xlsx file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, excel, date

I am reading data from an excel sheet and the 5th column is a date field. I have the following logic to ensure that the input date is converted to YYYY-MM-DD format -

```
var valid_from = new Date(data[counter][5]);
valid_from_new = var formatedDate = moment(valid_from).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
reqBody.valid_from = valid_from_new.toString();
```

I have the date `2017-10-10` to begin with and I am able to read it fine via my node app. It works for me as long as I do not edit this field in my Microsoft Excel 2010. If I edit it or simply find/replace the values, I get unix default date (1970-01-01) in reqBody.valid_from.

To find out what happens after the replacement, I checked that if I replace `2017-10-10` with `2017-10-20` and then "clear formats" (excel utility), I get `43028` displaying in the sheet, whereas for the date `2017-10-10` it remains the same, i.e. `2017-10-10`. I don't understand why excel behaves like this.

Can this be handled uniformly by my application? I just want to make the "YYYY-MM-DD" format work across any excel versions. It would be fine if I could do one format change or clear format once before feeding the file and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why excel behaves like this.

Excel behaves like that as it stores 2017-10-10 as a serial date.  Meaning it is an integer representing the number of days that have past since January 1st 1900 for the Windows system.  (potentially 1905 or something similar for mac).  In your specific case its apparently 43028.  It displays a converted date in a format people read as 2017-10-10 in your case.  You will note this as your formatting for the cell is either a date of some sort or a custom user format.  If you entered the date as text by leading it with a `'` you would note the format does not change when you change the cell formatting.  The date is actually just text and not a formatted date.  Numbers that are enter in a format that looks like a date to excel, excel will usually attempt to automatically convert them to a serial date value for you.  It has a built in list of formats it looks for and I believe also looks at your system settings format too.

As a side note, the decimal portion of the number represents time.  Fraction of a day. 0 is 00:00:00 and .5 is 12:00:00.

> Can this be handled uniformly by my application?

I am sure the answer to this is "yes" but is beyond my expertise.  I highly suspect it is because your code is handling it as text initially. Things go wrong when it receives the integer from excel that represents the date in excel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am parsing the value to string later. Do you think it could be an issue if I instruct the team which feeds the sheet into the system to ensure that the date fields are formatted to Text before?

Comment: usually dates stored as dates are nicer to work with as a lot of codes have special routines for dealing with dates.  so having it stored as a date sves you the proces of converting it later on.  Secondly, it may be less memory to store a date as a date instead of a string.  If you are going to get them to store it as a string first you will want of way of enforcing this or dealing with errors when it does not happen.